# Marketing Cloud Smart Capture and Subscriber Key

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, smart-capture

I am facing a quite bang-against-the-wall, but common (I believe), scenario:

- I have records in my NL Data Extension to which I send monthly newsletters.
- My All Subscribers List is therefore updated as new records are added or updated as I send newsletters and as subscribers unsubscribe.
- Aside from this, I have a Smart Capture form in a CloudPage, filling a Template-based Data Extension ("SmartCapture - Contacts Template Extension"). This Data Extension is Sendable and the Send Relationship is the following "Source relates to Subscribers on Subscriber Key".

How do you manage the fact that there are records with an email address that already exist in All Subscribers List with a specific Subscriber Key, that could fill the form and get a different Subscriber Key (for the same email address)?

Thank you in advance for your advice!

Best,
Stefano

Comment: Two questions: 1. What are you using as Subscriber Key in all subs? 2. "Source relates to Subscribers on Subscriber Key" sounds not very well configured? I would assume source was the form, hence not unique for each subscriber?

Comment: Hello ! Thank you for interacting!
My Subscriber Key is a subscriber_id coming from Magento

Comment: "Source" did sound odd to me too, and you're right... I therefore need to have a field that creates a new ID (incremental?) ? what do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing too much about Magento API capabilities, my approach would be following:

1. Create custom form on a Cloud Page
2. On landing page, fetch the details posted from the form
3. Call Magento API to verify if customer/subscriber with this email address already exists
4. If no, create a new customer in Magento
5. Upsert the customer/subscriber ID received back from Magento, along with other fields received from the form, to your central subscriber data extension (assuming such a DE exists)
6. You can now send out emails to records in this data extension, and mapping Magento subscriber ID to Subscriber Key on this sendable data extension will insert these individuals to All Subscribers in a consistent way

You can bypass step 5 above, if you have a high velocity data integration between Magento and SFMC, as it will upsert this record for you.